# solve "Unicode char is not set up for use with LaTeX" without special handling of every new interesting UTF-8 character

Tags: pdftex, unicode

on topic of duplicate claims - I tested [Tell Latex to ignore ALL unicode errors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307673/tell-latex-to-ignore-all-unicode-errors) - "solution" it resulted in LaTeX displaying "?" rather than ​"⌀".

Thanks to people who provided high quality and very useful answers.

---

I added ⌀ to text and now pdflatex is crashing with

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:⌀ not set up for use with LaTeX.

I know that I can use \DeclareUnicodeCharacter or similar to introduce special handling of this character but doing it every time that new UTF-8 character appears in the input is not acceptable.

It needs to work in pdflatex (or other pdf-generating latex compiler) as I use latex solely as pdf generator (LaTeX is generated from input, pdflatex generates pdf output).

MWE:

```
\begin{document}
⌀
\end{document}
```

MWE with my document declarations present

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 10.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% make TOC work correctly
\makeatletter
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{escape}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}
\CustomVerbatimCommand\escapeinline{Verb}{fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}

\begin{document}
⌀
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE. If other pdf-generating compilers are okay, try LuaLaTeX as this supports full unicode range.

Comment: `inputenc` mostly just supports alphabetic characters and punctuation. If you want to use technical characters (like the diameter symbol ⌀) it's better to use an engine with native UTF-8 support.

Comment: The solution is easy: get the unicode list, write down definitions for all 60.000 to 100.000 possible inputs and then load this file always. Btw: 00A0 is defined in a current latex, so you should perhaps update.

Comment: @TeXnician MWE posted

Comment: @TeXnician What is expected behavior of LuaLaTeX? In my case it silently ignored ⌀ in second MWE (and crashed on the first MWE). (note, I installed through apt-get from default packages).

Comment: what do you mean by "not acceptable" ?  What you describe is what LaTeX does, if you can not accept that what do you want us to do?

Comment: Well, remove everything font-related package and compile with LuaLaTeX and it should use LatinModern. This should support the character.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `what do you mean by "not acceptable"` - doing it every time that new UTF-8 character appears in the input is an ugly hack, doing once something that will fix issue of failing to process UTF-8 characters would be a solution. I prefer to avoid adding special handling every time new special character appears in the document.

Comment: note you have an old latex if the message is `\u:..` the current message is `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⌀ (U+2300)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: But saying you do not like something is a statement, but it isn't a bug report it is just a statement about the state of the world. There is no mechanical way to know of a suitable definition for every possible Unicode character.

Comment: Both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX work fine with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}⌀\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "it isn't a bug report" - maybe I missed something but AFAIK this is not a LaTeX bug tracker.

Comment: sure but you worded the question as a statement that the current behaviour is not acceptable, which is basically a bug report (it certainly is not a question) yes the referenced answer changes the default behaviour from an error to a ? what else would you want to do for an arbitrary undeclared unicode character? there are tens of thousands of such characters they can not all just work out of the box.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want UTF-8 support, as in "just display the character". As apparently this is impossible in LaTeX I will try alternatives.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny it is of course possible in latex but you showed the solution in your question so there is no answer to give.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny I don't think _any_ system is available that will allow you to input any Unicode 10 defined character as utf-8 input and have the character appear.. All systems have a range of characters that will work and a range that will not work without further customisation.

Comment: It's 2017 - why do you struggle with pdfTeX when we have XeTeX & LuaTeX that handle Unicode?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can think about it this way: for LaTeX (or any system) to draw “⌀” (or any character) onto the page/screen, the “shape” (visual appearance) of that character must be available to it *somewhere*.

## Outside the *TeX world

In most “modern” applications, text editors, browsers, and so on, this is implemented via a **font-fallback** mechanism:

1. the application (say your browser) first tries to find a glyph for that character in the current font. (As I type these letters on the tex.stackexchange.com website, they are being displayed in the “Lucida Grande” font, specified by the CSS on this site.)
2. if the current font does not support the character, the application tries to find *some* font installed on the system that contains a glyph for that character, then picks up the glyph from that font. (In this case, with the fonts installed on my computer, my browser shows the “⌀” character from the “Cambria” font, as the character is not present in the “Lucida Grande” font.)
   [image]
3. If there is no such font, then you may see a square box, a question mark, a blank space, or some such depiction that the character is missing (possibly from a “Last Resort” fallback font). For example, in the following texts showing the digits 0 to 9, for the odd digits I use the digits first from the [“Brahmi” Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmi_(Unicode_block)) (for which I have a font installed) and then from the [“Masaram Gondi” Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masaram_Gondi_(Unicode_block)) (added to Unicode in version 10.0.0, released only a few days ago in June 2017), for which I (and probably you too) don't have a font installed:

   > 02468 02468

   I see it rendered as in the image below; what do you see?

   [image: Brahmi Gondi]

## In the *TeX world

The above 1–2–3 description of the character rendering process does not hold in the TeX world, for two reasons:

- [**Solved with XeTeX/LuaTeX**] Partly because the roots of (La)TeX are very old, it is not straightforward to load a modern OpenType font from your system into a non-Unicode LaTeX engine (e.g. `pdflatex`). So even if you knew a font that contains the character you want, it is not straightforward in the non-Unicode engine to say “show the ⌀ character from the Cambria font”. Instead you can draw on a large number of (La)TeX-specific fonts, symbols available in many packages (see [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf)), and so on.

  - This is solved with XeTeX/LuaTeX: they are Unicode-aware by default, can use standard (Opentype) system fonts, etc. See example later below.
- [Not solved] Partly because of the goal of careful and precise typesetting, TeX-based engines so far don't automatically load random fonts: you have to specify the fonts you want. (And even if you know which fonts you want, there's [no straightforward way to specify fallback logic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323575/how-can-i-specify-a-chain-of-fallback-fonts-in-xelatex).) Personally I think this wouldn't be such a terrible idea to implement: for example the engine could stop, show you all the font options, and ask you which one you wanted. Instead, it does the ridiculous thing of silently printing a warning message, which by default is even [buried in the log file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/getting-xetex-to-complain-when-a-character-is-missing).

## Summary

Ways to get specific Unicode characters in LaTeX:

1. With `pdflatex`, load a particular package that can produce the shape you want (or even [draw it yourself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366019/unicode-with-pdflatex/366180#366180), or load an image), then write definitions for specific characters:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % To be able to write ⌀ in the first place
   \usepackage{fdsymbol}       % Contains a symbol for ⌀ -- use \diameter
   \usepackage{newunicodechar} % To write the definition on the next line
   \newunicodechar{⌀}{\ensuremath{\diameter}}
   \begin{document}
   ⌀
   \end{document}
   ```

   Note that if you load a different package that defines `\diameter` differently, you will get a different visual appearance.
2. With `xelatex`/`lualatex`, (use the above options or) use a font that contains that Unicode character. For ⌀ in particular, the default font (LMRoman10) actually already has it:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
   ⌀
   \end{document}
   ```

   (Just compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex` and it will produce a PDF file.)     But in general (for characters not contained in the default font, or for which you want a different appearance) you need to load the font explicitly:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \newfontfamily\cambria{Cambria}
   \newfontfamily\deva{Chandas}

   \begin{document}
   The following is in Cambria: {\cambria ⌀} and the following in Chandas: {\deva आ}.
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: loading fonts]

   Just remember to [set `\tracinglostchars=2`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/getting-xetex-to-complain-when-a-character-is-missing) and search for "Missing character" warnings in the output.

Answer (score 4):

You get an error telling you that there is no default definition for `⌀`, which is not present in any of the standard fonts.

The Comprehensive List tells us that `\diameter` is provided by

- `mathabx`
- `MnSymbol`
- `wasysym`

and it would be very disputable adding one of these packages just in order to make some symbol available.

You get an error message that tells you the precise details; make a choice, for instance `wasysym` and change your code into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 10.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{wasysym} % for \diameter

% make TOC work correctly
\makeatletter
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~} % not needed in recent versions of LaTeX
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2300}{\diameter}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{escape}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}
\CustomVerbatimCommand\escapeinline{Verb}{fontfamily=\rmdefault,breaklines,breaksymbolleft={}}

\begin{document}
⌀
\end{document}
```

You don't need `inputenc` with LuaTeX but you *do* need a font that supports the glyph.

Note that other software might make automatic font substitutions when a glyph is not available in the current font. LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX don't, because they're aimed at good typography and an automatic substitution may give a clash. The same idea as before: the kernel cannot provide a definition for every Unicode character, because this requires choosing from alternate fonts.

---

It is possible, though, that the user typed in U+2300 in order to get the `\varnothing` symbol, which is quite likely if the document is about math and not a technological topic. In this case, the package to load is `amssymb`:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2300}{\varnothing}
```

Comment: i know that `\diameter` is what is found for a symbol of this shape, but with the math-centric bias of tex (if not necessarily of tex.sx), i assume that what may really be wanted is `\varnothing` (which is in the `amsfonts`).  do, please, consider that possibility.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done. As you know, I consider `\varnothing` a symbol for plumbers, rather than mathematicians. `;-)`

Comment: well, yes, but it's the only one that, up until recently, the unicode committee has been willing to recognize.  (although they *did* assign it a separate code from `\diameter`, namely U+2205.  (according to my unicode contacts, the committee has relented, and will assign the slashed zero to that same code point with a variation selector.  i think it's in the pipeline.)  anyhow, thanks.