# I'm having troubles with special chars in listings

Tags: symbols, listings, characters

I'm using TeXMaker to make a document in LaTeX.
So I already made several listing blocks, and when some error occurred, I simply was making a new line, like this:

```
{ß}{{\ss}}1
{ü}{{\"u}}1
{ä}{{\"a}}1
```

And so on. 
But now I have trying in different ways to make this block like below, but no success. I think that symbols in beginning of each line (like `ﾟωﾟﾉ'`) are broken my code, but I really need of them. 
Can you help me to use them?
I need to use some package? I have tried japanese package and math package too, but no success.

I'm trying to make this listing:

[image]

Below is a real example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=THIS IS OK!]
Name.prototype = {
  methodName: function(params){
    var doubleQuoteString = "some text";
    var singleQuoteString = 'some more text';
    // this is a comment
    if(this.confirmed != null
    && typeof(this.confirmed) == 
    Boolean && this.confirmed == true){
      document.createElement('h3');
      $('#system').append("This looks great");
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Error;
    }
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=BUT THIS IS NOT OK! why?]
||   ﾟωﾟﾉ = Variavel { valor: undefined }
||   _ = Variavel { valor: 3 }
||   ﾟｰﾟ = Variavel { valor: 4}
||   o = Variavel { valor: 3}
||   ﾟΘﾟ = Variavel { valor: 1}
||   c = Variavel { valor: 0}
||   ﾟДﾟ = Variavel {
  valor: 
   { 'ﾟΘﾟ': Variavel { valor: 'f'},
     'ﾟωﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'a'},
     'ﾟｰﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'd'},
     'ﾟДﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'e'},
     c: Variavel { valor: 'c'},
     o: Variavel { valor: 'o'},
     _: Variavel { valor: [Function: Function]},
     return: Variavel { valor: '\\'},
     'ﾟΘﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'b'}}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You would help if you say what characters (language) are they. Probably the problem has to do with the encoding of your editor or the encoding of latex input (I mean that it could make sence to use inputenc or fontenc package) but I can not guess the language.

Comment: The simple answer is that the Latin Modern font family doesn't contain the glyphs. If you use a font like *Droid Sans Fallback*, they will be printed. But then you will discover other problems. `listings` is a pain to use with non-ascii characters.

Comment: Crosslink: Essentially a combination of [xetex - The 'listings' package and UTF-8 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396) and the general issue of "missing character from font" -- see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377729/250119 or [section 1.2 of my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628285/250119).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues at play.

First, unless you tell it otherwise `listings` uses the main document font. Except the Latin Modern font family does not have the Greek, Cyrillic, and Japanese glyphs you are using, so nothing prints.

We could use a font that contains everything. But it's an odd combination that won't be that easy to find. Instead, I'll use *Noto Mono* as the main mono spaced font. This contains Greek and Cyrillic glyphs, but not the Japanese ones. However, it's possible to substitute these for ones in the *Noto Sans Mono CJK JP* font. We do this like this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
% use Noto Mono as fixed pitch font
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}
% set up fall back font containing the missing Japanese glyphs
\newfontfamily\fallbackfont{Noto Sans Mono CJK JP}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{ｰ}{\textfallback{ｰ}}
\newunicodechar{ﾉ}{\textfallback{ﾉ}}
\newunicodechar{ﾟ}{\textfallback{ﾟ}}
```

You should now see all the glyphs in the listing.

But if you look, you'll notice that the position of the Greek, Cyrillic, and Japanese characters is wrong. You have to tell `listings` about them, which is a pain. Do it like this:

```
% fix up positioning of non-ascii characters in listings
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
    \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
      ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
      ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
      ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
      ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
      ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
      ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
      ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
      ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
      %   Θ       ω
      ^^^^0398^^^^03c9%
      %   Д
      ^^^^0414%
      %   ｰ       ﾉ       ﾟ
      ^^^^ff70^^^^ff89^^^^ff9f%
      ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother
```

And finally it will work as expected.

It's also possible to use the `minted` package. You will still need the font substitution stuff, but won't have to mess around to get the non-ascii characters to print in the right place. The downside of `minted` is that you need to compile it with the `-shell-escape` flag and you have to have the `python` backend stuff installed.

Here's the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\pagestyle{empty}
% use Noto Mono as fixed pitch font
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}
% set up fall back font containing the missing Japanese glyphs
% needed for both listings and minted
\newfontfamily\fallbackfont{Noto Sans Mono CJK JP}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{ｰ}{\textfallback{ｰ}}
\newunicodechar{ﾉ}{\textfallback{ﾉ}}
\newunicodechar{ﾟ}{\textfallback{ﾟ}}
% fix up positioning of non-ascii characters in listings
% only needed for listings
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
    \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
      ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
      ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
      ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
      ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
      ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
      ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
      ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
      ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
      %   Θ       ω
      ^^^^0398^^^^03c9%
      %   Д
      ^^^^0414%
      %   ｰ       ﾉ       ﾟ
      ^^^^ff70^^^^ff89^^^^ff9f%
      ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section*{Using listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{lstlisting}
||   ﾟωﾟﾉ = Variavel { valor: undefined }
||   _ = Variavel { valor: 3 }
||   ﾟｰﾟ = Variavel { valor: 4}
||   o = Variavel { valor: 3}
||   ﾟΘﾟ = Variavel { valor: 1}
||   c = Variavel { valor: 0}
||   ﾟДﾟ = Variavel {
  valor: 
   { 'ﾟΘﾟ': Variavel { valor: 'f'},
     'ﾟωﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'a'},
     'ﾟｰﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'd'},
     'ﾟДﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'e'},
     c: Variavel { valor: 'c'},
     o: Variavel { valor: 'o'},
     _: Variavel { valor: [Function: Function]},
     return: Variavel { valor: '\\'},
     'ﾟΘﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'b'}}
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Using minted}

\begin{minted}[fontfamily=tt]{text}
||   ﾟωﾟﾉ = Variavel { valor: undefined }
||   _ = Variavel { valor: 3 }
||   ﾟｰﾟ = Variavel { valor: 4}
||   o = Variavel { valor: 3}
||   ﾟΘﾟ = Variavel { valor: 1}
||   c = Variavel { valor: 0}
||   ﾟДﾟ = Variavel {
  valor: 
   { 'ﾟΘﾟ': Variavel { valor: 'f'},
     'ﾟωﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'a'},
     'ﾟｰﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'd'},
     'ﾟДﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'e'},
     c: Variavel { valor: 'c'},
     o: Variavel { valor: 'o'},
     _: Variavel { valor: [Function: Function]},
     return: Variavel { valor: '\\'},
     'ﾟΘﾟﾉ': Variavel { valor: 'b'}}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your help solved my problems. I only needed to change PDFLaTeX to XeLaTeX.