# Listings weird charater behaviour

Tags: xetex, matlab

I am trying to put in MATLAB code with comments that contain my language charaters thought they are covered under ANSI chars they jump to word begining in comments.[image]

Heres the code. Its basically sample code I got from OverLeaf wiki I think. Compiled with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% MATLAB koda bloki
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=Octave]{matlab.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411536/2388

Comment: Don't [mcode](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) (not preferable) or [matlab-prettifier](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) (preferable) work on XeLaTeX?