the czech letters are not correctly displayed at pdf level of generation
Can someone kindly help me to understand why most of the czech letters like "čšě" are not correctly displayed
after the generation of pdf ? E.g. "č" is simply omitted at the pdf output. My code is like this:
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    literate={á}{{\'a}}1 {č}{{\v{c}}}1 {ď}{{\v{d}}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {ě}{{\v{e}}}1
             {í}{{\'i}}1 {ň}{{\v{n}}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ř}{{\v{r}}}1 {š}{{\v{s}}}1
             {ť}{{\v{t}}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1 {ů}{{\.u}}1 {ý}{{\'y}}1 {ž}{{\v{z}}}1
             {Á}{{\'A}}1 {Č}{{\v{C}}}1 {Ď}{{\v{D}}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Ě}{{\v{E}}}1
             {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ň}{{\v{N}}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ř}{{\v{R}}}1 {Š}{{\v{S}}}1
             {Ť}{{\v{T}}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1 {Ů}{{\.U}}1 {Ý}{{\'Y}}1 {Ž}{{\v{Z}}}1
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

% ... (rest of the preamble remains the same)

\begin{document}

% ... (previous content remains the same)

\section{Results and Discussion}
\subsection{Complexity Analysis}
Our experiments revealed a significant increase in the number of legal positions and the depth of the game tree when non-standard pieces were involved. For example, in a King and Queen vs. King endgame, we observed:

\begin{lstlisting}[language={}]
Funkce calculate_optimal_moves byla zavolána
Počáteční FEN: 8/8/8/2k5/8/8/1K6/1Q6 w - - 0 1
Generování pozic dokončeno. Celkový počet pozic: 375676
Počet pozic v matu je 364
Počet pozic v patu je 872
Počet pozic v remíze je 7224
Počet pozic v šachu je 79072
Počet normálních pozic je 288144
\end{lstlisting}

These numbers are substantially higher than those for a King and Queen vs. King endgame in traditional chess, reflecting the increased mobility of the Queen.

% ... (rest of the document remains the same)

\end{document}

And the result is like this

Sorry, but I can't reproduce the issue. I get this picture (click)

@egreg Good. I'm using XeTeX, may be that this is the problem ?

I'm getting this error in WinEdt10.3: Missing character: There is no č ("10D) in font ec-lmtt8!

Oh, well, lmodern is wrong with XeTeX! As well as fontenc.

@egreg. Great observation. How do I fix it ?

There are two problems with your code

fontenc, inputenc and lmodern should not be used with XeLaTeX
you have to teach listings how to treat Czech characters

I used Ulrike Fischer's code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411536/4427, but augmented with the Czech characters in Latin Extended-A.
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

%%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411536/4427
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  % for Czech in Latin Extended-A block
  ^^^^010c^^^^010d^^^^010e^^^^010f^^^^011a^^^^011b^^^^0147^^^^0148%
  ^^^^0158^^^^0159^^^^0160^^^^0161^^^^0164^^^^0165^^^^016e^^^^016f%
  ^^^^017d^^^^017e%
  ^^^^2423% (open box)
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
%\makeatother


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    extendedchars=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

% ... (rest of the preamble remains the same)

\begin{document}

% ... (previous content remains the same)

\section{Results and Discussion}
\subsection{Complexity Analysis}
Our experiments revealed a significant increase in the number of legal positions and the depth of the game tree when non-standard pieces were involved. For example, in a King and Queen vs. King endgame, we observed:

\begin{lstlisting}[language={}]
Funkce calculate_optimal_moves byla zavolána
Počáteční FEN: 8/8/8/2k5/8/8/1K6/1Q6 w - - 0 1
Generování pozic dokončeno. Celkový počet pozic: 375676
Počet pozic v matu je 364
Počet pozic v patu je 872
Počet pozic v remíze je 7224
Počet pozic v šachu je 79072
Počet normálních pozic je 288144
\end{lstlisting}

{\ttfamily\raggedright\footnotesize
Funkce calculate\_optimal\_moves byla zavolána\par
Počáteční FEN: 8/8/8/2k5/8/8/1K6/1Q6 w - - 0 1\par
Generování pozic dokončeno. Celkový počet pozic: 375676\par
Počet pozic v matu je 364\par
Počet pozic v patu je 872\par
Počet pozic v remíze je 7224\par
Počet pozic v šachu je 79072\par
Počet normálních pozic je 288144\par
}


These numbers are substantially higher than those for a King and Queen vs. King endgame in traditional chess, reflecting the increased mobility of the Queen.

% ... (rest of the document remains the same)

\end{document}

I added the same text in standard format just to check that the typesetting is right.

